# Why do I still burn out the stack using tail recursive Fibonacci algorithm?

Tags: java, stack-overflow, dynamic-programming, tail-recursion, memoization

Stack overflows before n=1000. Is it because of the reference to the long[] parameter, that the JVM feels the need to hold on to every stack frame (wild guess), or am I doing something else wrong?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        fibonacciMemoized(1000);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("\nTotal run time: " + (end-start));
    }

    public static void fibonacciMemoized(int n) {
        long[] fibMemos = new long[n+1];
        for (int i = 0;  i < fibMemos.length; i++) {
            fibMemos[i] = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        long fibResult = fib(n, 1, 0, fibMemos);
        System.out.println(fibResult);
    }

    public static long fib(int n, long fibAcc, long fibPrev, long[] fibMemos) {
        if (fibMemos[n] != Long.MAX_VALUE){
            return fibMemos[n];
        } else if (n == 0) {
            return fibPrev;
        } else if (n == 1){
            return fibAcc;
        } else {
            long result = fib(n-1, fibAcc+fibPrev, fibAcc, fibMemos);
            fibMemos[n] = result;
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this is more of an answer than a comment:

> Why do I still burn out the stack using tail recursive Fibonacci algorithm?

Because Java doesn't support tail call elimination.

Comment: It supports it, you just have to write to yourself, hehe.

Comment: @Thomas: Well yeah, I suppose any language with loops "supports" eliminating tail calls :)

Comment: Well that explains a lot haha.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod - that is like saying assembly language supports functional programming.  This is NOT what people normally mean by "support".

Comment: In this case the right answer would also be "because you didn't actually implement a tailrecursive function". I mean yeah it wouldn't help in any case, but how would `foo(X): foo(X); bar=Y` be tail recursive?

Answer (score 1):

The key issue with memoization is that *subsequent* calls of a memoized function will use precalculated values for the same parameters.

In your code, you have not invoked the function before so there are no previous results to re-use, and you start invoking it with a value of 1000, which makes a recursive call at the end of `fib()` with  `fib(n-1, fibAcc+fibPrev, fibAcc, fibMemos)`, so you are blowing up the stack with 1000 recursive calls.

Comment: How do you get the values into fibMemos in a top down manner?

Comment: Ok, I think I see, this memoization scheme only works when you're still making 2 recursive calls, like 'fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)'.....

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it using options to increase the stack like java -Xss4m or more.

Note: Using -Xss sets the stack size of every thread and is a very bad idea.